# Evolution Mail Accounts not Listed in Client

Tags: email, evolution

I've found many instances of this problem but have not found any resolution.  I did my diligence, I think, on install of 14.04, by closely following the tutorial on things to do when upgrading; for instance, I've run a check on dependencies system wide.

I'm able to send and receive from three accounts but only one shows up in left panel of Evolution.  I've stopped and restarted the client, and Ubuntu (14.04) but still only see the FIRST account I created.

However, I do see three accounts in System Settings/Online Accounts; all three are Google duplicates, it appears; I doubt this has anything to do with Evolution, however, though one of my email accts. is gmail.  Note I've only created each of the three email accounts once.

How does one get all created email accounts to appear in Evolutions left panel?